# How to build Odoo 10 for windows as an executable software?

Tags: build, odoo, odoo-10

How to build Odoo 10 for windows as an executable software?

Is there any tutorial available for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Odoo custom build guide for Windows OS:**

I created this guide for my personal reference. So I try to keep it short and clear.

This will focus only on Odoo 8 in Windows 7 environment and can be easily adapted to later versions.

**OS:** Windows 7, **Odoo Version:** 8

1) Install Python27 (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

2) Install PIP.

Odoo windows packaging files are available at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/setup/win32

You have to be on Windows host to build .exe for Odoo due to the fact that the 
Makefile (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/Makefile#L7) was using the Cygwin's cygdrive emulated path.

3) Assuming that Windows was the host machine and we can proceed to install Cygwin (https://cygwin.com/install.html)

While installing Cygwin, you will get an option to select the supporting packages. Make sure you select the category `python` and `devel` with it.

Once Cygwin installation is done, open the Cygwin's terminal and enter "`make`". 
If you got "`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`", then you're good to go.

4) Use your favorite git client (mine is http://www.mingw.org/ or you can use the Cygwin if you want to) and clone the Odoo repo.

```
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --depth 1 --branch 8.0 --single-branch
```

Since we are building for `8.0`, a single branch is enough for this tutorial.

5) Install the dependency packages from the req.txt file from Odoo repo.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/requirements.txt

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/doc/requirements.txt

6) Static folder for the third party software's like **WkHtmltoPdf**, **PostgreSQL** etc are placed at this static folder.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/setup/win32/static

7) Download the PostgreSQL from https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ and place it under static folder.

8) For the **WkHtmltoPdf**, the recommended version is `0.12.1` and is available on the WkHtmltoPdf download page, in the archive section.

Download from http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/ and put the necessary files based on arch under static folder.

9) The images for the setup file needs to be placed on https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/setup/win32/static/pixmaps

10) Edit the https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/Makefile.version and enter `VERSION=8.0`

Files you might be interested in:

**Service:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/win32_service.py

**Setup:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/win32_setup.py

**Makensis:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/setup.nsi

**Package:** https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/package.py

11) Change the **NSI** file based on your need which is available at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/setup.nsi

If you are using the **NSIS** from the http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ and installed at a different location from the default, you may have to change the path to makefile on the following file:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/setup/win32/Makefile#L12

12) Finally, the build command is
Open the Cygwin's terminal and navigate to https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/setup/win32.

Enter "`make -f Makefile`"

On the successful run, final "`openerp-allinone-setup-8.0.exe`" will be available in the same folder.

Comment: thanks for step by step guide. :)

Comment: @no coder, After reading, some questions arises:
-- Step 1 and 2 believe have to be done on the host itself (no cygwin);
-- Steps 4-5 are to be executed on windows machine or on cygwin? There is, should I install de dependecies on cygwin or on windows? And as per the Odoo repo? Should I pull it under windows or cygwin?
-- Last: I believe from step 6 I have to do everything from windows host and not cygwin. So, my question is, how can I navigate to my local Odoo repo structure via cygwin? I will need to do it on step 12?